# Not able to understand Indexer in C#

Tags: c#, indexer

I was going through some code and come across with indexer and i am not able to understand how it is working, here is my code

```
public class FlyweightFactory
    {
        Dictionary<string, FlyweightFactory> flyweights = new Dictionary<string, FlyweightFactory>();
        public void display() { }
        public FlyweightFactory this[string index]
        {
            get
            {
                if (!flyweights.ContainsKey(index))
                    flyweights[index] = new FlyweightFactory();
                return flyweights[index];
            }
        }
    }
    class Client
    {
        // Shared state - the images
        static FlyweightFactory album = new FlyweightFactory();
        static void Main()
        {
            Client client = new Client();
            album["A"].display();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
```

in this code i have created an Indexer like this

```
public FlyweightFactory this[string index]
        {
            get
            {
                if (!flyweights.ContainsKey(index))
                    flyweights[index] = new FlyweightFactory();
                return flyweights[index];
            }
        }
```

but i when i am trying to make a Indexer like this i am getting an error

> album["A"];

but at the same time when i use like this it is working fine

> album["A"].display();

please help me understand the working of Indexer, thank you

Comment: And what's the error you're getting?

Comment: "i am getting an error" What error?

Comment: It's simple: you can't use an indexer (or a property, or a constructor) as a statement on its own. You can't write `"text".Length;` or `new object();`. But you can use `var x = "text".Length;` and likewise you could write `var factory = album["A"];`

Comment: @JonSkeet `new object();` is a valid statement...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I'm sorry, `new object();` is useless, but allowed code; `new MyObject();` can even be reasonable if the instance created is used in the constructor `public MyObject() {s_Instances.Add(this);}`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko It doesn't even need to be that contrived; the constructor could simply cause side effects, even if the object instance is dropped on the floor entirely.  (Interestingly though, so could a property getter, but just invoking a property getter is not a valid statement.)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: You're absolutely right about the constructor call being allowed (not sure what made me think it wasn't) - but I don't buy the "because it could have side-effects" argument, as a property access or indexer access can have side-effects too.

Comment: @JonSkeet We can obviously only guess as to why the language designer choose to allow it.  What we *can* say is why someone might conceivably actually write code that *does* it, given that it's possible, and we could say that such code isn't necessarily pointless (although it may not be good design).

Comment: @Servy: My main annoyance with it not being valid is within `Assert.Throws` calls :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write such statement in C# and it will emit the following error:

*error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement*

Such statement does not fit any of the categories told in the error message.

To fix the error assign this statement to a variable:

```
var myValue = album["A"];
```

**Now for the indexer:**

It allows you to access an item in a collection by the means of a specific key type, in an array you commonly access items by their index such as:

```
int[] ints = {0, 1, 2, 3};
var int1 = ints[0]; // get first element
```

But you can implement a different type than `int`, here I used a `string`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace Tests
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // generate some data
            var artist = new Artist {Name = "Britney", Surname = "Spears"};
            var artists = new[] {artist};
            var collection = new ArtistCollection(artists);

            // find an artist by its name, using the custom indexer
            var artist1 = collection["Britney"];
        }
    }

    public class Artist
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }

    public class ArtistCollection : Collection<Artist>
    {
        public ArtistCollection()
        {
        }

        public ArtistCollection(IList<Artist> list) : base(list)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Gets an artist by name.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Artist this[string name]
        {
            get
            {
                if (name == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
                var artist = this.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Name == name);
                return artist;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have to admit it was such a dump question and i was battling over it for more than 4 hours, may be its time for coffee, thank you for your help :)

Comment: but still i have a question and let me update it for you

Comment: Actually it is strongly advised that you post **another** question if it's out of the scope of the current one, in StackOverflow :)